# Organize Cypress tests in categories or environment

Tags: cypress

How do I organize my Cypress tests based on the environment. I am running my Cypress tests against both a mock server and a real server.

While running against mock server I can assume that data is always there and can run the full set of tests, but I can only run a subset of the tests when pointing to a real server.

One option of course is to move them to different folder/spec files, but is there any other better way e.g. like barreling files through `index.ts`?

What's the convention in Cypress to organize tests based on environment?

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/optimumqa/cypress-multi-product-template) may help you. It's a template cypress project that lets you easily split tests per product, team, environment, and type. What's left for you to do is just to create the tests in specific folders, and create JSON files in configs to strictly specify which tests to run per which npm command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you set up your dummy data for tests with the mock server you may might it useful to add `@tags` to your tests using [`cypress-grep` plugin](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep).

This will allow you to run certain tests with tags and place a `@realServer` tag for your test only to be ran against your real server.

You may need to alter however you set up the `baseUrl` for each subset of tests.